# In Workaway, do you pay for the plane ticket, or does the host?

Tags: hostels

I want to try to volunteer with Workaway, but I want know first whether I or the host will pay for the plane ticket. Because if I need to pay, maybe I can’t afford it.

Comment: Soory, we have no idea what workaway is. If it's an organization, you should ask them.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't done much research...

The [Information for Workawayers](https://www.workaway.info/information-for-travellers.html) page states:

> Remember though, Workaway.info is not an agency. We enable you to find placements. **It is up to you** to write yourself a great profile, to make contact, to introduce yourselves with an e-mail, **to organize your travel arrangements**, to arrange your travel visas, and to discuss directly with your host the ways in which you can volunteer , work or help.

Comment: "arrange your travel visas" is another sticking point - many countries regard these sort of schemes as work, not volunteering, and the companies themselves (shamefully, I think), tend to skim over the fact that you can get into real trouble at the border

Comment: @nkjt types faster than I do. Being found to have used or tried to use a tourist visa (or visa-free travel) to work can have long term consequences, not just loss of that one trip. Some countries count even pure volunteering, in which you pay all your expenses, as work, except under specific conditions. Even more require a work visa for any sort of barter, such as work for food and shelter.

Comment: The same things came to my mind when I read about the whole concept. Also when you read elsewhere on their site that "Generally you will be expected to volunteer around 5 hours per day in exchange for food and accommodation" and "some hosts may give a paid allowance to ensure they are offering at least the minimum wage in their country", that triggers quite a bit of head-scratching.

Comment: In the UK room and board can only be counted towards a set amount per week - they may well need to top it up to hit minimum wage. This is fine if the "volunteer" is UK or (until Brexit) EU, or on a working holiday visa, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You pay for your flights and arrange any visas - with workaway, you are only working for your food and lodging, nothing else.